# Updating default index mapping in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to update default mapping in elasticsearch for my index. But all the doc point out that we have to provide type for updating mapping. Problem is that I have lots of index types and they are created dynamically as in when a doc for new type appears. So the best way to deal with is default mapping type. as I dont have to define mapping for each type. But now I am not able to update my index default mapping. If it is possible please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

I used [default mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/default-mapping.html) as follows:

I created the index, specifying the `_default_` mapping. In this case I only have a single field, but I want to make sure that it doesn't get analyzed (so I can do faceting across types, say):

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/test_index"

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index" -d'
{
   "mappings": {
      "_default_": {
         "properties": {
            "title": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Then I created a couple of documents, each of a different type:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/doc_type1/1" -d'
{ "title": "some text" }'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/doc_type2/2" -d'
{ "title": "some other text" }'
```

So the mapping for each type will be generated dynamically, and will include the default mapping for `"title"`. We can see this by looking at the mappings:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test_index/_mapping"
...
{
   "test_index": {
      "mappings": {
         "_default_": {
            "properties": {
               "title": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               }
            }
         },
         "doc_type2": {
            "properties": {
               "title": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               }
            }
         },
         "doc_type1": {
            "properties": {
               "title": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And if I facet on the `title` field I will get back what I expect:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/_search" -d'
{
    "size": 0, 
    "facets": {
       "title_values": {
          "terms": {
             "field": "title",
             "size": 10
          }
       }
    }
}'
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "facets": {
      "title_values": {
         "_type": "terms",
         "missing": 0,
         "total": 2,
         "other": 0,
         "terms": [
            {
               "term": "some text",
               "count": 1
            },
            {
               "term": "some other text",
               "count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/05c503ce9ea841ca4013953b211e00dadf6f1549

Does this answer your question?

**EDIT:** Here is how you could update the `_default_` mapping for an existing index:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/_default_/_mapping" -d'
{
   "_default_": {
      "properties": {
         "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
         },
         "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

(I used Elasticsearch version 1.3.4 for this answer, by the way.)